# UIPickerView won't move on scrollview

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a UIScrollView that has a UIView as a subview. This UIView contains a UIPickerView. The UIPickerView does not move when I try to scroll. Reading other posts it seems that having a picker view on top of a scroll view is a problem. I'm confused why this could be an issue because I have a UIView in between. Also, how would I fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```